# How to redirect a request to localhost?

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, firewall, iptables

I created an iptables-rule:

```
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.XXX.XX/32 -d 192.168.YYY.YY/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65430 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:65435
```

I even used `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, but it still doesn't work.
But it worked to redirect the request to an other port via

```
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.XXX.XX/32 -d 192.168.YYY.YY/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65430 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.YYY.YY:65435
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need `REDIRECT`

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.XXX.XX/32 -d 192.168.YYY.YY/32 -p tcp --dport 65430 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 65435
```